# loop to select items consequently from drop down list in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, bots

There is a list of 4 items I need to loop between the 4 items using (select_by_index) and do a function called reserve() after selecting each item

My code is:

```
driver.get('https://foreupsoftware.com/index.php/booking/20290#/')
driver.maximize_window()

course=driver.find_element(By.ID,'schedule_select')
dropdown_1=Select(course)
dropdown_1.select_by_index(0)
    
course=driver.find_element(By.ID,'schedule_select')
dropdown_1=Select(course)
dropdown_1.select_by_index(1)

course=driver.find_element(By.ID,'schedule_select')
dropdown_1=Select(course)
dropdown_1.select_by_index(2)

course=driver.find_element(By.ID,'schedule_select')
dropdown_1=Select(course)
dropdown_1.select_by_index(3)


def reserve():     
    non_passholder_button=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@class="btn btn-primary col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4"][contains(., "Non Passholder")]')
    non_passholder_button.click()
```

Comment: In which step are you stuck? Do you see any error?

Comment: i don't know how can i automate the script to select the first item in the list then call the function (reserve() ) and then select the second item in the list and call the function (reserve() ) and so on till the list ends , i believe loop can solve the issue but i don't know how to apply it here

Comment: we can't run your code so we can't help you. Better create minimal working code with real URL so we could run it.

Comment: @DaliaTawfeek What does the function `reserve()` does?

Comment: i've provided you with the full code, please check

Comment: @DaliaTawfeek I don't see you calling `reserve` anywhere, also what is `Select`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar this is where i need help, i need a help to adjust  my code by adding a loop so that the bot select each item and then after each time call the function reserve()

Comment: And you need to do that in a loop for all drop down item?

Comment: yes, that is it exactly

Comment: BTW the end result is you just going over to all the options right? its not necessary to go over them by clicking on the drop down right?

Comment: i need to click on each item in the list not only just go through them

Comment: So as I understand the script should click on each dropdown on this page `https://foreupsoftware.com/index.php/booking/20290#/` right?

Comment: yes click on the first item then click on non passholder button, then click on the second item and click on same button, so on

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the web page I found that the url is made up of options present in the dropdown. So first you can get all the options in the page and then you can go through each url which is constructed using the option.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get(url)
  
options = driver.execute_script("""
    var result = [];
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("option");
    for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
        result.push(all[i].getAttribute('value'));
    }
    return result;
""")
  
for option in options:
    value_url = f'https://foreupsoftware.com/index.php/booking/20153/{option}#/teetimes/'
    driver.get(value_url)
    non_passholder_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[contains(text(),'Non Passholder')]")
    non_passholder_button.click()
    # the page has been opened after the click 
    # DO YOUR STUFF HERE
```

**EDIT :** As discussed the OP wants the options to be clicked mandatorily and does not want to go over each page by constructing a url.

This is how you can do it

```
url = 'https://foreupsoftware.com/index.php/booking/20155/3782#/teetimes/'
driver.get(url)
option_index = 0
  
num_of_options = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#schedule_select > option'))
  
while(option_index < num_of_options):
    facility = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'schedule_select')
    facility.click()
    
    drop_options = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#schedule_select > option')
    drop_options[option_index].click()
    
    non_passholder_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//button[contains(text(),'Non Passholder')]")
    non_passholder_button.click()
    
    # DO YOUR STUFFS HERE

    driver.get(url)
    option_index += 1
```